# How to get vendor name and version of libraries used in java project through java program

Tags: java, jdepend

I am able to get library list used in my java project using J Depend using simple java program as bellow,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import jdepend.framework.*;
//import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ConstraintTest {
    private JDepend jdepend;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDepend jdepend = new JDepend();

        try{
            jdepend.addDirectory("C:/abc-workspace/example");
                jdepend.analyze();
                Collection collection=jdepend.getPackages();
                for (Iterator iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                JavaPackage type = (JavaPackage) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(type.getName());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }  
}
```

out put for above program i.e for "example" project.

```
java.util
java.io
jdepend.framework
java.lang
com.example
```

Now my task is to find Vendor name and the version number for above libraries. Is it possible to get these information from J Depend?.

Comment: It (j)depends (pun intended) on what the vendor has willed to provide as informations... Sometimes you may have nothing at all. If you use maven, you have the artifacts information; if not, you'll have to rely on whatever is in this jar's name and MANIFEST.MF if anything.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. Can you understand my need? I just asked whether is able to get vendor name and version of libraries used in my java project using J Depend? If yes how can I?

Comment: I did understand. What I say is that as this information is not standardized in any way, you'll have to resort on the good will of vendors/heuristics to get this information.

Comment: ya got. I cannot do this job using J Depend. Thank you